# Generating data for testing

Tags: testing

I need to test number-analytics-intensive product, so ideally I would use a copy of production database and tested left and right for numbers not "adding up".

The problem is, I don't have one (production database) available. And I can't just populate tables with random numbers and strings, because of the inherent business logic of data itself.

Any ideas? Any tools that could be at least partially useful? Some secret plugins for Excel combined with clear head and functioning brain?

Note that I'm talking about millions of records. I would settle for thousands to be frank, but I don't think I can realistically test the thing with less than that.

Comment: Have you looked into using [Equivalence partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) at all?

Comment: There's tools for this. Free, even AFAIR. E.g. **[Microsoft PEX/MOLES & advanced Unit-Testing aspects 1/3](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/channel9spain/Microsoft-PEXMOLES--advanced-Unit-Testing-aspects-13)**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with millions of rows doesn't work. If a test fails, a human brain needs to be able to see **why** it fails. You should settle for dozens or hundreds of records - don't just feed random data to test cases.

When you want to test a method that sums numbers, try to feed it with 1-5 numbers. Feeding it with millions will probably not give you any useful information. Same with calculating averages: 2+2+0+0+0+0+0+0+...+0 gives you exactly the same average as 2+2.

So you need to look at your code, determine each feature you want to test and then write a test for each *individual* feature. Avoid "I'll just dumps tons of data through the code; maybe *something* will happen."

Along the same lines, you should have user stories that explain in detail what you should test, how it can be tested (i.e. the full input and the expected results). If someone tells you "this can't be tested", they are omitting a vital piece of information: "... without a lot of effort" (well, unless your product behaves perfectly random).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like Datanamic's [Data Generator](http://www.datanamic.com/datagenerator/index.html). It sells itself on being able to 'Generate meaningful test data'. It's not cheap but the trial period may help you achieve what you want.